# Paypal OAuthTokenCredential causing java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createSecurityManager")

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paypal, sdk

I have below code which is causing exception in local google app engine (development server):

```
File fl = new File("/sdk_config.properties"); 
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = PayPalResource.initConfig(fl);
```

sdk_config.properties file is located in folder src\main\resources.

This is the complete stack trace :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:503)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:149)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:120)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:331)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:283)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:304)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.<clinit>(PayPalResource.java:30)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
    at net.bloodweb.userresources.TtrdetailURS.checkAndSavePaymentProof(TtrdetailURS.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    ... 47 more
**Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createSecurityManager")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.Util$ClassContextSecurityManager.<init>(Util.java:43)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.Util$ClassContextSecurityManager.<init>(Util.java:43)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:49)
    ... 76 more**
```

What is causing this ?

Comment: Title says "AccessControlException" but stacktrace for "NoClassDefFoundError". Which of them is correct?

Comment: Thanks Igor, i have put the correct error stack trace. Any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: what do you have at `PayPalResource.java:30`?

Comment: private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PayPalResource.class); It is a standard Paypal Java SDK library.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33637960/1836506) proved to be the problem in my case.  As a temporary workaround, I added this to my `pom.xml` and it fixed the problem:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

As a permanent solution, I filed [this pr](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/pull/145) with the folks at PayPal.